# How to pass 'method parameter' with HEAD request?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have one HEAD restAPI which contain some parameter.

Example:

```
HEAD http://server:port/myservice/rest/v0.1/myStore?storeid='123'
```

- I have added `/myservice/rest/v0.1/myStore` in Path of Http Request.
- Changed Method to `HEAD`.
- Added Parameter `storeid=123` in `Send Parameters With the request` section.

When I execute JMeter script then it not sending parameters with path.
It's showing Request as `http://server:port/myservice/rest/v0.1/myStore` instead of
`http://server:port/myservice/rest/v0.1/myStore?storeid='123'`.

Note: If I change method to GET then it's working fine.
But my requirement is HEAD request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put parameter in Path field as:

> ?storeid='123'

Comment: not for now, but if you know about a real case, open an enhancement request showing it, implementing it should be simple.